# First Screen. Shown on first Launch, ONLY

Tags: android

I want that when the users install my application and launch it for the first time try areshown " features of the application " but then that screen can neverbe accessed by the user. It should never display again on the same device,ever. It's just like, Showing an Initial Screen on first launch and no initial screen on subsequent launches. Any idea or example as to how can that be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences` to set a flag. Define a key, and in your `onCreate()`, check if it's set or not. If it's not, display the window and write the key to preferences.

```
private static final String FIRST_LAUNCH = "first_launch";

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();

//Assume true if the key does not yet exist
if (prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, true)) {
    //Display window
} else {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, false);
    edit.commit();
}
```